# Serialization and Deserialization in unity3d c# for Dictionary and GameObject

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, serialization, json.net

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    public GameObject a;
    public SerializableDictionary<int, ExampleClass2> b = new SerializableDictionary<int, ExampleClass2>()
    public int c;
    protected string d;
    protected XYZ e;
}

ExampleClass exampleClass = getExampleClass();

string exampleClassData= JsonUtility.ToJson(exampleClass );


string exampleClassDataJsonDotNet = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(exampleClass );
```

For the above code while serialization if I use `JsonUtility.ToJson` its missing to serialize the `SerializableDictionary<int , ExampleClass2> b` , its serializing protected because I added `[SerializeField]` and ExampleClass2 is also Serialization supported.

If I used `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` its working great will all types but unable to Serialize `GameObject`

Are there any solution to make it work in any of ways?

Comment: So `b` isn't serialising - is that the issue? Does it work if the key is `string` rather than `int`?

Comment: haven`t tested it because ExampleClass is 3rd party asset and it needs to be like that. So I might need something to make above work

Comment: You can't serialize GameObject. For dictionary, use thirdparty(Newton) API

Comment: but while using JsonUtility gameObject is serialized as `"gameObject":{"instanceID":844016},"`